# Visual c# - avoid huge nested if for collision detection?

Tags: c#, nested, collision

Sorry, I'm a total novice - I've searched for an answer to this but nothing quite matches what I am doing.

I have a basic arrow controlled maze game, with labels for "walls" , named Label1, Label2, etc.

When I press a key, it detects the intersection between the character and the walls.

I am doing this currently with a large nested if, as follows :

```
            if (PBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(LblWall1.Bounds))
            {
                PBoxPlayer.Location = new Point(CurrX - 10, CurrY);

            }

            else if (PBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(LblWall2.Bounds))
            {
                PBoxPlayer.Location = new Point(CurrX - 10, CurrY);

            }

            else if (PBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(LblWall3.Bounds))
            {
                PBoxPlayer.Location = new Point(CurrX - 10, CurrY);

            }
```

But this is becoming very messy.

Is there a way I can just say - if player hits 'any' wall, then move it back to it's previous position?

I realise the above is probably an bad way to code, but I am happy with the action on screen just not the repeating code behind it.

Comment: Thanks Jon that is /exactly/ the sort of thing I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by putting all the "collision-interesting" objects into a collection, for example:

```
var walls = new[] { LblWall1, LblWall2, LblWall3 };
```

There's bound to be a better way to do this as well, but it's not obvious because there's no context for this. So keep that in mind and let's go on.

Having all the objects in a collection enables you to use LINQ:

```
var collision = walls.Any(w => PBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(w.Bounds));
if (collision) {
    // adjust location
}
```

If the wall with which the player has collided is itself a useful piece of information, you can use another variation:

```
var collidedWith = walls.FirstOrDefault(
    w => Bounds.IntersectsWith(w.Bounds));
if (collidedWith !== null) {
    // collidedWith is the wall we ran into
}
```

Comment: I would go even further to just store the walls in a list anyway to begin with, rather than reference them in a new list (assuming there isn't any game logic that would prevent this)

Comment: @Sayse: I suspect there's already a collection that includes these instances -- from the description it seems this is a WinForms app with `Label` controls standing in for walls.

Comment: Ah true, in which case if these are the only labels in the game (I doubt this) there is always `Controls.OfType<Label>()` (Extra +1 for the use of FirstOrDefault btw, I never really thought of using it in this way.. going straight into my own code)